# Meteor: Manual Deployment

Tags: deployment, meteor, meteor-up

Do you guys have any experience on manual deployment for Meteor? I'd love to hear some feedbacks.

We have a client that has a strict IT policy. And they won't allow 3rd party to touch their servers. So we do it like this:

1. Fill up some form that explains our app specs.
2. Send them a zip of the app's source code & db dump.
3. Wait for them configure the server and test our app.
4. Get feedbacks and send back revisions if any.
5. Pray to whatever god we have that they manage to deploy our app.

**Basically i want to know how to bundle a Meteor project and send it to our client for deployment with minimum effort on their side.**

This used to be a pretty straightforward process with our standard LAMP stack. But things are not so simple anymore these days.

Answer (score 0):

Create an test a mup (meteor up) file for a test server, then send the whole project to them with a mup directory set up for their server and tell them how to call mup setup/deploy.